# Search-Engine with MySQL NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, search-engine

I'm trying to build my own search engine with MySQL.
It gets a text like "Stackoverflow+MySQL+SearchEngine", splits it into array [Stackoverflow,MySQL,SearchEngine] and feeds to MySQL like in the following:

```
var text = filter.split("+");

var sql_statement = ' (title LIKE "%'+text[0]+'%" OR detail1 LIKE "%'+text[0]+'%") ';
for(var i = 1; i < text.length; i++){
                sql_statement += ' AND (title LIKE "%'+text[i]+'%" OR detail1 LIKE "%'+text[i]+'%") ';
}

pool.query('SELECT thread_id,username,date,price,title FROM threads_mphp WHERE'+sql_statement+'ORDER BY thread_id DESC LIMIT ?, ?',[startLimit,amount], function(error,results,fields){});
```

The database checks if those words exist in either "title" or "detail1".
The problem is, it only works only upto 3 words with independant order.
If I use more words and random order it won't find the result in the Database. Am I doing something wrong?

Example: Database item Title:"First question in Biology".
Strings that will find this item: "bio" ,"biology question","first question in bio", "bio first".
Strings that wont find this item: "Biology in question first","biology question first"

Comment: Unrelated sidenote, it's best to use placeholders rather than string concatenation to guard against SQL injection attacks

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I thought the NodeJS module will escape the string in '?' already, but I will check that out.

Comment: Oh it will, I was referring to using `?` in places like this `' AND (title LIKE "%'+text[i]+'%"` where you are concatening the `text[i]` string

Comment: Yeah, no problem. This doesn't seem particularly high-risk but I just thought it was worth mentioning. You could alternatively manually escape using `mysql.escape` so you don't have to worry about figuring out the placeholder array

Comment: Can you include some test cases and database items where your code works and also some where it doesn't work to give us a better idea? I don't immediately see anything wrong with what you're doing

Comment: You may want to do fulltext search using `SELECT * FROM threads_mphp WHERE MATCH(title, detail1) AGAINST('Stackoverflow MySQL SearchEngine' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)` but i think you also need to add the columns to fulltext index `CREATE TABLE threads_mphp .... FULLTEXT(title, detail1)` https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

Comment: Your test cases seem to work for me (I used your script to generate the statement and then executed the statement in MySQL Workbench against a test table with the database item you provided). The only change I had to make was to make sure the words were in the correct casing